# How to check if an object is derived from an interface?

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism, derived-class

I have some classes that are derived from an interface, and I would like to be able to check in code to see if an object that is passed in is derived from that interface, but im not sure exactly the method calls ...

```
interface IFile
{
}

class CreateFile : IFile
{
    string filename;
}

class DeleteFile : IFile
{
    string filename;
}

// Input here can be a string or a file
void OperateOnFileString( object obj )
{
    Type theType = obj.GetType();

    // Trying to avoid this ...
    // if(theType is CreateFile || theType is DeleteFile)

    // I dont know exactly what to check for here
    if( theType is IFile ) // its not, its 'CreateFile', or 'DeleteFile'
        print("Its an IFile interface");
    else
        print("Error: Its NOT a IFile interface");
}
```

In actuality I have hundreds of derived classes from that interface and i'm trying to avoid having to check for each type, and having to add the check when I create another class from that type.

Comment: .Net type names should be UpperCamelCase, and interfaces should start with `I`.

Comment: Your coding conventions are terrible and really lower the readability of your code. I suggest you put in a little more effort if you want other people to read your code and answer questions on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`is` is exactly correct.
However, you need to check the instance itself.

`obj.GetType()` returns an instance of the `System.Type` class that describes the object's actual class.

You can just write `if (obj is IFile)`.

Comment: Tizz, SLaks is correct here. I'd also suggest not passing in 'obj' as an object. If you pass in a 'file', any call will be forced to pass in an object that implements 'file'. Also, be careful of your naming conventions and casing. In C#, we prefer to use interfaces that start with I, so IFile in this case.

Answer (score 6):

1. `is` operator works or you can do:

   ```
   if (someInstance is IExampleInterface) { ... }
   ```
2. or

   ```
   if(typeof(IExampleInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type)) {
    ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the wrong argument to `is`. The correct is

```
if (obj is file) {
    // ...
}
```

However it would be even better if you had an overload of the method that directly accepts a `file` parameter. In fact it's quite unclear how one that accepts an `object` could efficiently use it.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You could use `BaseType`:</s>

```
if (type.BaseType is file)
```

Since `file` is an interface, use [Type.GetInterfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx) to check the underlying interfaces of `type`:

```
if (type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.Equals(typeof(file))
```

Or probably a bit faster, use [Type.GetInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayfa0fcd.aspx):

```
if (type.GetInterface(typeof(file).FullName) != null)
```

(This searches the interfaces of `type` and of any inherited classes or interfaces.)

Answer (score 2):

```
If( yourObject is InterfaceTest)
{
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create an extension method like below

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return true if two types or equal, or this type inherits from (or implements) the specified Type.
    /// Necessary since Type.IsSubclassOf returns false if they're the same type.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsSameOrSubclassOf(this Type t, Type other)
    {
        if (t == other)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (other.IsInterface)
        {
            return t.GetInterface(other.Name) != null;
        }
        return t.IsSubclassOf(other);
    }

    and use it like below

    Type t = typeof(derivedFileType);
    if(t.IsSameOrSubclassOf(typeof(file)))
    { }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd do this